# Delete node from every child of node with Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Sorry if my question phrasing sucks.

I've already managed to do it in Java with a Query like this:

```
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (snapshot.child("trendingviews").exists()){
                    snapshot.child("trendingviewedby").getRef().removeValue();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Database structure is like this:
[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT0RQ.png)
Is there a function like that existent in FIrebase's Cloud Functions, and if so could anyone lead me into the right direction?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript the equivalent code would be:

```
const reference = firebase.database().reference("Posts");
reference.once("value").then((dataSnapshot) => {
  dataSnapshot.forEach((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.hasChild("trendingviews")) {
      snapshot.child("trendingviews").ref.remove();
  });
})
```

To learn how to run and deploy this on Cloud Functions, I'd recommend following the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: huh, that's really close to Swift code. Thank you so much.

Comment: Btw: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.